# DATEDIFF problems

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, datetime

I'm trying to create one activity query and there I need to pick all the records
where the diference between today and my fieldDate has a result equal or minus then 4 months.

e.g fieldDate will have a date in the future like 01/09/2018 and for this case my query should find this result because the difference between today and the date I give is 4 months or less.

I already made a lot of attempts to get all the records in this condition and I fail all the time.

e.g:

```
WHERE MyFieldDate <=DATEADD(DAY, 120, CAST(GETDATE() AS date));
WHERE DATEDIFF(week, CONVERT(date, getdate()), MyFieldDate)<=16; 
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, CONVERT(date, getdate()), MyFieldDate) <= 4;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datediff always confuses me, so I tend to avoid it.

If you want to return all rows where `fieldDate` is less than 4 months from today, you could do something like this:

```
select
d.fieldDate
from DataExtensionNameHere d
where d.fieldDate <= dateadd(month, 4, convert(date, getDate()))
```